# How do I use JQuery to add a sub-array to JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, maps

I'm trying to create a JSON object as follows:

```
var request = {
    location : pyrmont,
    radius : '50000',
    types: ['amusement_park', 'store'] //Here I want to replace with a javascript array 
};
```

This JSON works fine as an input to the Google Maps API but when I try to replace with 
a javascript array as such it fails.  Any help is appreciated!

```
var allVals = [];
$('#geo_form :checked').each(function() {
  allVals.push("'" + $(this).val() + "'");
});
alert("allVals -> " + allVals);  //allVals -> 'amusement_park','lodging'

var request = {
    location : pyrmont,
    radius : '50000',
    //types: ['amusement_park', 'store']
    types: [allVals]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`allVals` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in brackets in the `request` object. By wrapping the array in brackets you set the `allVals` array as the zero most index of a new array.

```
var request = {
    location : pyrmont,
    radius : '50000',
    types: allVals
};
```

Also, you don't need to wrap the value in quotes when you push it on to the array as it is already a `String` object.

In fact, you could avoid declaring a variable outside of the request object by creating an empty array within the request object initially and push onto the object by directly accessing the property.

**Example:**

```
var request = {
    types : []
};
request.types.push($(this).val());
```

For most data structure issues, it is wise to print the object to the console debugger to see what values are contained within the object. Firefox has the popular `firebug`, Chrome, Opera, and new versions of IE have a console debugger built in.  use the method `console.log(arg)` to print.

Comment: To expand: [ ] is shorthand for say "new Array()", so what you're asking it to send when you type [allVals] is "new Array(allvals)", which creates array( 0 = array( /* the allVals keys and values are in here */ ) )